# Exception in WPF DataGrid Cell Editing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm getting the below error while edit the cell event in WPF DataGrid.

[image]

Could you please help me resolve the issue?

The below Code I Have used for editing Cell Value

**Cell Edit Code :**

```
private void AutoBook_Datagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
            {
                int primaryKey = 0;
                DataRowView editedRow = (DataRowView)mainWindow.autoBook_Datagrid.SelectedItems[0];
                if (editedRow != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(editedRow.Row["ID"].ToString()))
                {
                    primaryKey = Convert.ToInt32(editedRow.Row["ID"]);
                }
                if (e.EditingElement.ToString().Contains("TextBox"))
                {
                    if (e.EditingElement != null)
                    {
                        UpdateTextBoxValue(e.EditingElement as TextBox, e.Column.Header.ToString(), primaryKey);
                    }
                }
                else if (e.EditingElement.ToString().Contains("CheckBox"))
                {
                    if (e.EditingElement != null)
                    {
                        UpdateCheckBoxValue(e.EditingElement as CheckBox, e.Column.Header.ToString(), primaryKey);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**XAML Binding :**

```
<DataGrid
                    x:Name="autoBook_Datagrid"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource GreenBrush}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    RowHeight="25"
                    GridLinesVisibility="All"
                    ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding DynamicBindingTable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    CanUserAddRows="{Binding CanAddNewRows, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                    VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                    EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                    EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                    FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"
                        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                    >
```

**Error Message :**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

Parameter name: element
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(UIElement element)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.CellAutomationValueHolder.TrackValue()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ReleaseCellAutomationValueHolders()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)

Regards,
Arunkumar Murugesan

Comment: There is not enough data, please add more info, provide us some code snippets:  datatypes that you use in datagrid, you table described in xaml. Also add WPF tag to your question.

Comment: Hi Shakra, I have added code snippets in the question

Comment: What does 'UpdateCheckBoxValue'? Is there any input params called 'element'?? Did you checked all params for 'NULL' in debug?